# Getting min and max values from timeseries for each day

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

So is there any quick and easy way to iterate through data frame? My index is a date, and my other column is the difference between two time series. What I want to do is to get `min()`, `max()` and `avr()` values for each unique day.

```
            difference
date
2017-07-08      505017
2018-01-12      232143
2018-02-04      127792
2018-03-06       98835
2018-03-09      146702
2018-03-12       64094
2018-03-14       84029
2018-03-14       87257
2018-03-20      172057
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been helpful if you had provided a DataFrame with more than one duplicate, but you can use `pd.Grouper` and `agg`:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1D')).agg({'difference': ['min', 'max', 'mean']}).dropna()

           difference
                  min       max      mean
date
2017-07-08   505017.0  505017.0  505017.0
2018-01-12   232143.0  232143.0  232143.0
2018-02-04   127792.0  127792.0  127792.0
2018-03-06    98835.0   98835.0   98835.0
2018-03-09   146702.0  146702.0  146702.0
2018-03-12    64094.0   64094.0   64094.0
2018-03-14    84029.0   87257.0   85643.0  # This was the only duplicate
2018-03-20   172057.0  172057.0  172057.0
```

Comment: that was exacly what I was looking for. Thank you